# Selenium Webdriver - Cannot find element by id

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to figure out why I can't manage with some elements.
I have tried with Id, Class, CssSelector but this element refuse to corporate.

This is the HTML code:
[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdi2K.png)

Now I'm trying to send keys with some string into this search line.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "txtsearch")]
public IWebElement SearchLine { 
   get;  
   set; 
}
```

and later I'm just clicking on it inside a method.

```
SearchLine.SendKeys("some string");
```

the error I'm getting in Visual Studio is:

> **could not find the element by: By.Id: Vertical.**

Comment: Please paste the HTML as text and not image. Also, post an example of your class: Selenium is probably running another piece of code. Are you sure the id is unique? Have you tried with the correct casing? ( **txtSearch** instead of **txtsearch** in your C# code)

Comment: any suggestions how to copy the html content?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
any suggestions how to copy the html content?

 it's written txtsearch in the Html code.
actually I'm not sure the id is unique. how can I make sure? would this error shown in case that the id is non unique?

Comment: <tr>
                    <td style="width: 10%">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="width: 30%; padding-left: 8px;" align="left">
                        <input type="text" id="txtSearch" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #94c3d6; height: 19px;" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 10%;">
                        <div style="width: 26px; height: 26px; border: 1px solid #94c3d6; border-radius: 2px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="Search();">
                            <img src="new_styles/default/search_btn.png"

Comment: @Yanif open the HTML with any text editor and manually search for that ID. If you find it twice, it's not unique. You can put all yout HTML here for example: http://pastebin.com/ then edit your post and add the link to the pastebin snippet.

Comment: @ Alessandro Da Rugna
Thanks.
I have noticed that when saving the html code and opening it with notepad, the 'txtsearch' element does not show there. how come?

Comment: ok. solved it. I had to switch to frame first.
 driver.SwitchTo().Frame("any frame");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to switch to frame first. driver.SwitchTo().Frame("any frame");